# Unable to execute curl request PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am working on curl, and trying to get results from a url, when I hit the url through command prompt then it works, but when I try to hit it through curl then it returns nothing in response.

Here is the URL and the curl request I tried:

```
$request =  'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<AccountSid>/Calls/<SID>/Recordings.json -u <AccountSid>:<AccountToken>';
```

When I try to hit the above URL via terminal then it works:

```
$ curl -G https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<AccountSid>/Calls/<SID>/Recordings.json -u <AccountSid>:<AccountToken>
```

it returns response in json format, but I want to access it throught curl, so I tried the following way:

```
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

but it returns nothing.

Comment: So what error does the cURL call return? You code does not implement _any_ error checking or handling...

Comment: The authentication data is not part of the actual request URL. You want to set `CURLOPT_USERNAME` and `CURLOPT_USERPWD` for that part.

Comment: @CBroe oh! thanks alot dear, i was not aware of that at all, you saved my time :) :)

Comment: @CBroe if you post it as an Answer then i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$request =  'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/
                <AccountSid>/Calls/<SID>/Recordings.json -u <AccountSid>:<AccountToken>';
```

The authentication data is not part of the actual request URL;
This is just how you feed HTTP Auth credentials to the *command line* version of cURL.

You want to set CURLOPT_USERNAME and CURLOPT_USERPWD for that part with PHP's cURL wrapper.